# Возвращения particle system

Tags: unity3d

У меня за шариком идет система частиц, что-то на подобии трейла, и если шарик ударяеться то телепортируеться на начало, но проблема в том что система частиц реализована так что спавниться от пройденной дистанции, и если шарик телепортрнуть, то система частиц не появиться пока не наблизиться к ней, т.е. не засветить её.

Видео с проблемой - https://youtu.be/8kZt5Etq8WM , проблема только при игре

Comment: Замечательно! Держите нас в курсе. А где сам вопрос?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский так нужно что бы система частиц телепортировалась вместе с шариком

Comment: Сделайте объект с компонентом ParticleSystems дочерним шарику, а в модуле Main системы частиц параметру Simulation Space задайте значение Local. Скорее всего эти действия решат проблему.

Comment: дочерним шарику он был изначально, но мне то нужно симулияцию в world,

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос. Добавьте конкретику, скриншот настроек системы частиц. А главное - понятнее опишите, чего Вы хотите, а то "засветить", "наблизиться", "появиться" вгоняют меня в тоску и только запутывают. А еще мне кажется странным, что шарик может телепортироваться, а частицы обязательно должны корректно вести себя в WORLD-координатах и при этом тоже телепортироваться...

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский обновил